# user level session_start_time and session_end time from clickstream data

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

Input

```
session_id |user_id|session_time        
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:00  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:01  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:02  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:03  
s1         | u2    |2021-01-01 00:00:04  
s1         | u2    |2021-01-01 00:00:05  
s1         | u2    |2021-01-01 00:00:06  
s1         | u2    |2021-01-01 00:00:07  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:08  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:09  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:10  
s1         | u1    |2021-01-01 00:00:11
```

Output

```
session_id|user_id|session_start_time|session_end_time
s1        |u1     |2021-01-01 0:00:00|2021-01-01 0:00:03
s1        |u2     |2021-01-01 0:00:04|2021-01-01 0:00:07
s1        |u1     |2021-01-01 0:00:08|2021-01-01 0:00:11
```

We need to write a SQL query to get the above output from the input data without using LEAD() and LAG().

Comment: As far as I'm concerned - forget it. You need a grouping column out of nothing. One that changes every time that the combination of session id and user id changes. So, for example, `1` for `s1|u1`, then `2` for `s1|u2`, and `3` when it becomes `s1|u1` again.

Comment: please elaborate what users and sessions are. are sessions shared among users? your example suggests that but it could evenwel be that usersessions are unique

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use running count distinct user+session

```
with mydata as(--test data, use your table instead of this CTE
select 's1' session_id,'u1' user_id,'2021-01-01 0:00:00' session_time union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:01' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:02' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:03' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:04' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:05' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:06' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:07' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:08' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:09' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:10' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:11') 

select session_id, user_id, min(session_time) session_start_time, max(session_time)session_end_time
from 
(
select session_id, user_id, session_time, 
       count(distinct session_id, user_id) over (order by session_time) cnt_user_session
 from mydata
)s group by session_id, user_id, cnt_user_session
order by session_start_time
```

Result:

```
session_id  user_id session_start_time  session_end_time
s1          u1      2021-01-01 0:00:00  2021-01-01 0:00:03
s1          u2      2021-01-01 0:00:04  2021-01-01 0:00:07
s1          u1      2021-01-01 0:00:08  2021-01-01 0:00:11
```

It will not wok if the same user repeats again: adding more u2 s1 records will produce the same running count and it will not work, so, the LEAD or LAG is necessary.

Using LAG we can calculate flag when session changes and use running sum of flags to calculate new_session_id (to be used for grouping):

```
with mydata as(
select 's1' session_id,'u1' user_id,'2021-01-01 0:00:00' session_time union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:01' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:02' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:03' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:04' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:05' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:06' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:07' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:08' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:09' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:10' union all
select 's1','u1','2021-01-01 0:00:11' union all
select 's1','u2','2021-01-01 0:00:12' --added this record 
) 

select session_id, user_id, min(session_time) session_start_time, max(session_time)session_end_time
from 
(
select session_id, user_id, session_time,
       sum(changed_flag) over (order by session_time) new_session_id
from 
(
select session_id, user_id, session_time, 
       case when concat(session_id,'_', user_id) <>
                 lag(concat(session_id,'_', user_id)) over (order by session_time)
              then 1
            else 0 
        end changed_flag
 from mydata
)s 
) s
group by new_session_id, user_id, session_id
order by session_start_time
```

Result:

```
session_id  user_id session_start_time  session_end_time    
s1          u1      2021-01-01 0:00:00  2021-01-01 0:00:03
s1          u2      2021-01-01 0:00:04  2021-01-01 0:00:07
s1          u1      2021-01-01 0:00:08  2021-01-01 0:00:11
s1          u2      2021-01-01 0:00:12  2021-01-01 0:00:12
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Can you also please provide the query using LEAD and LAG?

Comment: @PrashantSrivastav added one more record to get more sessions, see the solution with LAG

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get a grouping id out of nothing. I usually name the grouping ID obtained in this way with `session_id` - but, as you have already used that column name, I name it `session_key`.

Two nested OLAP queries:

The first adds a counter that is at 1 when any two columns  `session_id` or `user_id` change over time, otherwise at 0.

Tracking changes over time require either `LAG()` or `LEAD()`, I'm afraid ...

The second, selecting from the first, creates a running sum of that counter, returning the `session_key`.

Finally, I group by `session_key` , `session_id` and `user_id` , and get `MAX()` and `MIN()`

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                   
indata(session_id,user_id,session_time) AS (
          SELECT 's1','u1',DATE '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u1',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:01'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u1',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:02'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u1',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:03'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u2',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:04'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u2',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:05'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u2',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:06'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u2',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:07'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u1',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:08'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u1',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:09'
UNION ALL SELECT 's1','u1',TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01 00:00:10'
)
,
with_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE WHEN (
       session_id <> LAG(session_id) OVER(ORDER BY session_time)
       OR user_id <> LAG(user_id   ) OVER(ORDER BY session_time)
         )
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS counter
  FROM indata
)
,
with_session_key AS (
  SELECT
    session_id
  , user_id
  , session_time
  , SUM(counter) OVER(ORDER BY session_time) AS session_key
  FROM  with_counter
)
SELECT
  session_key
, session_id
, user_id
, MIN(session_time) AS session_start_time
, MAX(session_time) AS session_end_time
FROM with_session_key
GROUP BY
  session_key
, session_id
, user_id
ORDER BY
  session_key
, session_id
, user_id
;
-- out  session_key | session_id | user_id | session_start_time  |  session_end_time   
-- out -------------+------------+---------+---------------------+---------------------
-- out            0 | s1         | u1      | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 00:00:03
-- out            1 | s1         | u2      | 2021-01-01 00:00:04 | 2021-01-01 00:00:07
-- out            2 | s1         | u1      | 2021-01-01 00:00:08 | 2021-01-01 00:00:10
```